# Why do I see size of vector as zero?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers

```
void pre_process(string& pattern, vector<int>& c)
{
    c.reserve(pattern.length());
    c[0] = -1;
    c[1] = 0;
    for(int i=2; i<pattern.length(); ++i)
    {
        if(pattern[c[i-1]] == pattern[i-1])
            c[i] = c[i-1]+1;
        else
            c[i] = 0;
    }
    cout << c.size() << endl; //why the size is zero here?

}
```

After reserving the space in vector, I am assigning values to different positions of vector. So shouldn't the size be increased?

What is the right way to use vector as a fixed length container?

Comment: "I am assigning values to different positions of vector" - no you're not; you're invoking UB.  `reserve` does't `resize()`.

Comment: Short summary: You're seeing the size of the vector as zero because the size of the vector *is* zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) doesn't resize a vector. It simply re-allocates a larger chunk of memory for the vector's data (and copies elements from the original if necessary).

You need [`std::vector::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) for that:

```
c.resize(pattern.length());
```

Currently, you are accessing `c` out of bounds.

Alternatively, you can keep the call to resize and use push_back instead of `operator[]`

```
c.reserve(pattern.length());
c.push_back(-1);
c.push_back(0);
```

Comment: What would be use case scenario for std::vector::reserve ? If it simply reallocates more memory which is not usable, then what's the point in having such a function?

Comment: Do I save on reallocation while using push_back when the allocated memory is less than needed?

Comment: @aj_ If you know the vector is going to be of up to a certain size, but you want to push elements into it, `reserve` is a good option. But if you resize to a size that is too small, at some point you will need a re-allocation. If you don't do anything, and just push into the default constructed vector, you would get more re-allocations.

Comment: So essentially reserve() followed by push_back() and resize() followed by operator[] are equivalent?

Comment: @aj_ Not completely. `resize` will construct objects in place and the call to `operator[]` will modify those objects. `reserve` doesn't create any objects, it just reserves space for them. So the end result is the same, but the semantics, and what happens behind the scenes, is different, and may impact performance.